# How many Star Wars Storm Troopers have there been?

Tags: part-identification, minifigures, star-wars

How many different storm-troopers are there in the LEGO Star Wars sets
for the entire timeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [LEGO wiki on Fandom](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/Stormtrooper), there have only been 7 different variants of the plain white Stormtrooper minifigure since they were introduced in 2001 (plus one Chrome-Silver variation).

If you also include [Clone Troopers](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/Clone_Trooper), [Sand Troopers](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/Sandtrooper), [Snow Troopers](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/Snowtrooper), [Scout Troopers](https://lego.fandom.com/wiki/Scout_Trooper),  and other such armored soldiers from the Star Wars universe, that number would be much, much higher (also see 'Variations' at each of the links above).

Comment: Hi Christopher, welcome to Bricks.SE. [This post on Eurobricks](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/157676-compilation-list-of-lego-stormtroopers-ever-released-since-2001/) lists quite a large number of stormtroopers. I haven't compared all the minifigures. Does it confirm your answer? I think there are more than 7 white stormtroopers listed.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that article does provide a more comprehensive list of stormtroopers (including sand troopers, storm trooper disguises worn by Luke and Han, first order troopers, and more). I suppose the answer to the question varies depending on your definition of what is a storm trooper variant and what is a different figure entirely.